# Why is "+=" operator used in this auction example?

Tags: contract-debugging

Here's an auction code from **[blog.ethereum.org](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/10/smart-contract-security/)**

```
contract auction {
  address highestBidder;
  uint highestBid;
  mapping(address => uint) refunds;
  function bid() {
    if (msg.value < highestBid) throw;
    if (highestBidder != 0)
      refunds[highestBidder] += highestBid;
    highestBidder = msg.sender;
    highestBid = msg.value;
  }
  function withdrawRefund() {
    uint refund = refunds[msg.sender];
    refunds[msg.sender] = 0;
    if (!msg.sender.send(refund))
     refunds[msg.sender] = refund;
  }
}
```

> refunds[highestBidder] += highestBid;

What's the reason behind using "+=" instead of "="?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Bidder sends 100, Bid 1.
- Bidder gets outbid, 110, Bid 2. 100 refund due.
- Bidder bids 120, Bid 3. This is new money, still owed 100.
- Bidder gets outbid again, 130, Bid 4. Now owed 220.
- Bidder withdraws 220.